# Why does ldapsearch not show user's supplemental groups?

Tags: ldap

I have a user who when I type 'id username' shows more groups than when I query ldap using ldapsearch. What switch do I use?

```
$ id apanda
```

uid=14510(apanda) gid=5010(sambauser) groups=5010(sambauser),10001(graphics)

```
$ /usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -L -h localhost -D "cn=usermanager,ou=profile,dc=e-derp,dc=com" -w sUp3rSeKreT -b ou=people,dc=e-derp,dc=com |grep apanda
```

dn: uid=apanda,ou=people,dc=e-derp,dc=com
mail: apanda@ederp.com
sn: apanda
cn: apanda
gecos: Alicia Panda
homeDirectory: /home/apanda
uid: apanda

I suspect the missing groups are Samba groups only in effect when the user logs into specific servers. Is there any way to see those?

Comment: are those groups definitely defined in LDAP, rather than say, in a local /etc/group file?

Answer (score 0):

Supplemental groups are not often directly attached to a user object in ldap. If your ldap does, grepping for the username will likely remove it from the output as they are displayed on a separate line each. Try this command instead:

$ /usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -L -h localhost -D "cn=usermanager,ou=profile,dc=e-derp,dc=com" -w sUp3rSeKreT -b ou=people,dc=e-derp,dc=com sn=apanda memberof

Otherwise you need to search for group objects which contain the user you're looking for.